# Add SAVE button to Custom Form

Tags: javascript, save

I have a custom HTML form and I need to add a second save button to my form on the top.

So I created my button and can not find the right javascript function that will submit my form.
Basically, I just want the SAVE button from the bottom of the form, a second time.

What is the save function then?

I tried but without full success. It seems to submit but dont close the form after:

```
<script>
//Save function
    $('.saveForm').click(function() { 
        $("input[value$='Save']").attr('value', "Submit");
    });
//Set up button
    $( ".saveForm" ).button();
</script>
```

If I use the debugger from Internet Explorer, I can see the following code for the SAVE button. Could it be reused somehow?

```
onclick="
if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl39$g_72f104b2_2e10_4b81_9692_a4c10eacd37f$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))"
```

Answer (score 1):

I played a bit again with the code and it seems to works now

```
//Save function
    $('.saveForm').click(function() { 
        if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
        if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;
        WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('ctl00$ctl39$g_72f104b2_2e10_4b81_9692_a4c10eacd37f$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem', '', true, '', '', false, true))
    });
//button
    $( ".saveForm" ).button();
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can use that by removing the existing click event for save button and add your custom click event please find below sample which i did for my approve button
I have added additional confirmation on click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var approvebutton = $('[value="Approved"]');

            approvebutton.removeAttr("onclick");
            approvebutton.click(function() {
            return confirm('are you sure you want to approve?');if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
    if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('ctl00$ctl49$g_ee2ab7f9_8310_408f_a556_5718bc7de59b$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem', '', true, '', '', false, true)

    });
```

Comment: Nothing after the `return confirm();` will execute...

Comment: You don't keep return confirm('are you sure you want to approve?'); in your case only keep this one in click event
`if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
    if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('ctl00$ctl49$g_ee2ab7f9_8310_408f_a556_5718bc7de59b$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem', '', true, '', '', false, true)`

Comment: I'm not here for help, I was just reviewing the question.  I happened to notice your answer contained code that will never execute, because it's behind a return.  Why have the code if it'll never execute?

Comment: Who are you man?  I am just giving hit to Romain so that he will analyze how to keep the script.  he already said that he identified the script and it is working `onclick="
if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('ctl00$ctl39$g_72f104b2_2e10_4b81_9692_a4c10eacd37f$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem', '', true, '', '', false, true))"`